# Elasticsearch 6.2.4 not giving data to query

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch running on docker (docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:**6.2.4**) which is not returning data to any of our queries. Pasting my query and response below.

```
query:
*curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/full_sessions/_doc/_search"*

Result:
*{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}*
```

We have data in it, I tried the same via kibana but no luck but **I can see data from Discover option in kibana**

[Screenshot of Kibana Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD0pF.jpg)

[Screenshot of kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nrqN.jpg)

```
Query: 

curl -XGET "http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/indices"


yellow open xxx_full_sessions xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 5 1 175721     6 245.6mb 245.6mb


Query: 

curl -XGET "http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/health"

{
  "cluster_name": "docker-cluster",
  "status": "yellow",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
  "active_primary_shards": 626,
  "active_shards": 626,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 15,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 97.65990639625585
}
```

Anyone had faced this issue. Please give me some insights.

Comment: Can you try the search query without `_doc`, just `/full_sessions/_search`?

Comment: Thanks. got the hit count ("total": 175723) but not all data is showing there. Parts of result pasted below. How can I view entire data or N number of data from it
-------------
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 175723,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {

Comment: Use the `size` parameter: `/full_sessions/_search?size=100` (max is 10000)

Comment: Thanks Val.
Its resolved I removed _doc from my query and seems working fine. Really appreciate your swift reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to remove `_doc` from your URL as your mapping type might be named differently.

Just run this instead

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/full_sessions/_search"
```